# javascript get size of element with hidden parents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to determine the height of a DOM element using javascript - specifically, in my case, a div containing some text. Due to the way that HTML works, I can only reliably do this if the element is visible. The general purpose solution is to show the element, get it's height, and then hide it - simple enough in the single element case.

However, in the general case, the element in question may be a child of other elements that are hidden, thus preventing the above solution from working - calling jQuery's `show()` function on the element in question doesn't actually cause it to be shown due to the hidden parent, so you still can't get the height.

How can I make an element visible long enough to get its height, taking into account any parent elements that need to be made visible to make it work?

Use case: I'm trying to write some code that I can apply to any table element, that creates some other elements whose height should match the height of the table header. I want to keep the code generic enough that it will work regardless of where in the DOM the table is located, or if it is currently visible. An alternate solution would be to have some javascript that simply adjusts the size of the created elements when the size of the table header changes (such as when it is shown), but conceptually that seems less efficient. Still, if it is easier, I will accept that as an answer.

Edit: To give an example, while keeping in mind I am going for a general solution that is not tied to this specific HTML layout, consider the following HTML:

```
<div style="display:none; line-height:22px; font-size:18px;">
    ...Some random text or other content...
    <div id="desired_size">
        I want to find the height of this div when visible
    </div>
    ...Possibly some more content/other stuff...
</div>
```

The goal is to get the height of that inner div, but I can't do that because it isn't displayed - it is hidden due to the parent div being hidden. If all I know about the HTML is the `desired_size` div, how would I go about making it visible enough to get the height? Granted, this example is trivial, but I'm trying to generalize it.

Edit 2: One suggestion was to clone the element and move it to somewhere that is visible. This works, but with a caveat: any inherited CSS properties that would affect the size are lost.

Edit 3: I'm trying to write a block of code that I can re-use in a variety of web pages, not just coding to a specific layout. As such, I can't make any assumptions about or changes to the parent HTML. The example above shows one case where this can cause difficulties.

Edit 4: As has been pointed out, it would be trivial to change the HTML such that the visual appearance is the same, but the issue doesn't exist. However, I am trying to find a solution that works with the HTML *as written*, regardless of how the HTML is written.

Comment: Far too vague without some sample html

Comment: @JonathanLam Love to, but I can't think of anything *to* try other than looping over `.parent()` and calling `show()` repeatedly, checking for `.is(':visible')` after each call, until the object in question is visible, then *somehow* restoring everything to original state. And that approach is so ugly I'd rather *not* try it unless I have to, especially considering that I don't know how I'd restore things to the original state.

Comment: Are you getting an incorrect value using jQuery's `.height()`, or getting no value at all?

Comment: @JonathanLam whole issue relates to you can't get dimensions of hidden elements

Comment: @ibrewster depending on css involved you might be able to clone the element and put it into an off screen container and test it there. Need a [mcve] if you want assistnce

Comment: @charlietfi: *simple* example added. The problem with clone and offscreen is that you lose any CSS properties the object might inherit from its parents (such as font size/line spacing), so you could wind up with a different size than what actually will be displayed.

Comment: @charlietfl Ok, I added a couple more styles to the parent div, which illustrate why the "copy and move" approach doesn't work. I'll edit the code as needed to make it more "complete" should other approaches turn out to not work.

Comment: @: check my answer and let me know....

Comment: @LucaFilosofi Yeah, unfortunately sidestepping the original problem isn't an option. The idea here is that I have no knowledge of or control over the DOM - all I have is a reference to the object in question. This is because I want to write the code in such a way that I can re-use it in a variety of situations.

Comment: @ibrewster: still can't get the point, if you can add display:none why you can't add opacity?

Comment: @LucaFilosofi I'm not adding `display:none`. That is part of the original HTML. I can't change the original HTML, I'm trying to find a solution for the problem it creates. To use an analogy, If I have a flat tire and I'm asking how to change it, you can't answer me by saying I should have a tire that isn't flat :-) The tire is flat. The HTML is "flawed", as it were. That's the reality I have to deal with. Now how do I change the tire?

Comment: @ibrewster: i have updated my answer, anyway, the fact that you can't change the hidden parent manually, does not mean that you can't change it via javascript.

Comment: @LucaFilosofi True. I can make all the changes I want in javascript, as long as I change them back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following javascript/jQuery function should work in the general case where the HTML structure is unknown, as requested:

```
function getHeight(objectID){
    var object=$('#'+objectID);
    var nextObject=object;
    var changedObjects=[];
    var counter=0; //to prevent infinite looping
    while(!object.is(':visible') && counter<100){
        counter+=1;
        var curObject=nextObject; //store a reference for use in loop
        nextObject=curObject.parent();
        var curStyle=curObject.css('display') //see if current object is hidden

        if(curStyle!='none')
            continue; //don't mess with non-hidden objects

        //see if the display style is inline, or from a CSS file
        var inlineStyles=curObject.attr("style");

        if(typeof(inlineStyles)!=='undefined'){
            inlineStyles.split(";").forEach(function(element){
                var style = element.split(":");
                if ($.trim(style[0]) === 'display') {
                    //Record the fact that the display properly is an inline style
                    curObject.data('floatinghead_inline_style',true);
                    return false; //break out of the forEach loop
                }
            });
        }

        curObject.show(); //if object is hidden, show it for now
        visitedObjects.push(curObject); //save a reference so we can put it back later
    }

    var height=object.height(); //this should work properly, since object should now be visible

    visitedObjects.forEach(function(item){
        if(item.data('floatinghead_inline_style')===true)
            item.hide();
        else
            item.css('display','');
    })
}
```

The above code makes no assumptions about the HTML structure, particularly the depth of the object in question from the hidden parent element. Also, unlike the "clone item to a different, visible, location in the DOM" option, it should properly take into account any inherited attributes that affect the height.

Answer (score 1):

**demo** - http://jsbin.com/tosusanowu/edit?html,js,output

---

> Assuming you know that `desired_size` div has always a `parent` that is hidden.

```
$(function(){
    var desired_size = getDesiredSize('#desired_size');
});

function getDesiredSize(el) {
    var $el = $(el), $parent = $el.parent(), desired_size = 0;
    $parent.attr('style', 'opacity:0;position:absolute');
    desired_size = $el.height();
    $parent.attr('style', 'display:none');
    return desired_size;
}
```

---

```
<div style="display:none;">
    ...Some random text or other content...
    <div id="desired_size">
        I want to find the height of this div when visible
    </div>
    ...Possibly some more content/other stuff...
</div>
```

Comment: ...but then the object, technically, isn't hidden. If I could change the HTML so the object wasn't hidden in the first place, there wouldn't be a question because it would just work.

Comment: @ibrewster: can't understand your point... if you can't see the element it is tecnically hidden IMHO. anyone with a little bit of CSS skill can change both `display` and `opacity` to whatever they want and see it, as well as anyone can change the input text form `type="password"` to `type="text"` and see the password in plain...

Comment: I guess I'm not being clear: I have some HTML. That HTML has a parent where `display:none` is set. That can't be changed, that is the starting point of the issue. Given the original constraint (that there *is* a parent element with `display:none` set), how can I temporarily find and remove that `display:none` such that the element is displayed and I can calculate the height?

Comment: @ibrewster Well, if the parent element has `display:none` and you are absolutely forbidden to change that, then you can create of copy of the desired element, make than one `opacity:0` and call `getDesiredSize(copyOfElement)`

Comment: This works with the assumption that you state. So in the general case that I asked for, would you suggest putting this in a loop and walking up the ancestor tree until the object becomes visible?